# Binding mac and 2 IP addresses using IMBP

Tags: vlan

I had newly bought a D-link 1210 28 port switch, and I need to configure something. I can bind a particular mac id and IP address to a specific IP, but in my case I need to bind 2 IP of 2 different networks and a mac to a specific port on my switch. Kindly suggest me a solution, or else an alternative method for doing the same.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?  This is a layer 2 switch, so it knows nothing about IP addresses.

Comment: Using IMBP under security features in D-Link switches. I need to bind the mac address with 2 different networks for a specific port. I have already figured out to bind a mac and a IP to a specific port using the Port Guard settings. But in my case, I need to bind 2 different IP and a mac id to that specific port. Or else a different approach for doing this. for understanding, i have PC with 2 statically assigned IP's. I need to bind these IP and mac id of my PC to a specific port in the switch.

Comment: So in your question, "to a specific IP" should read "to a specific *port*"? Have you tried simply creating 2 bindings on the same port, with same MAC address and different IP address? If that fails, what does the error say?

Comment: the scenario is, i have an IP phone which is connected to a specific port. the 2nd port of the IP phone needs to be connected to the PC for Internet connection. So in my case, I need to bind both the IP(different n/w for IP phone and PC) and both their mac address to that specific port, so that no can access the port other than these 2 devices. When I tried to bind the 2 different IP's and mac's to the specific port, my IP seems to work but I am not getting internet access to the PC which is connected to the second port of the IP phone. If there is an alternate, kindly suggest it